# Push existing project to remote server

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using git. And I try to push a existing project to the remote server.

But I get every time this error:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin/master'

How to solve this error?

Screenshot of Visual Studio:

[image: screenshot]

I got this error:

```
Niels@WSDH29 MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git push https://verploe...
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream https://verpSANA.. master
```

and if I do this:

```
Niels@WSDH29 MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git push origin https://verpNA...:master
error: src refspec https://verploeg... does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

Comment: Try `git remote add origin https://.....`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Visual Studio extension is misinterpreting the error message from the git command and/or server.

The actual problem here is that you have incoming commits that should be fetched and merged with your local commits before pushing. You're not allowed to push multiple tips onto the server.

If you were to try pushing using git (other than through Visual Studio) you would get this error message:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '.....'
```

So do a fetch and then a merge, or do a pull, to integrate the incoming commits with your local commits, and then you should be able to push.

Comment: Thank you for your answare. But how to do that? I am totally new with GIT. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just try it through command line at first. I'm very sure that git will give you more descriptive error message. If 'Lasse V. Karlsen' is right you are gonna need to use such commands like pull/rebase/merge.